# Why do i not see the folder "GAC_MSIL" in C:windows/assembly - while cracking DevComponents(DotNetBar)?

Tags: winforms, components, windows-forms-designer, cracking, dotnetbar

I was trying to make use of DevComponents in c# windows forms. so I downloaded and installed DotNetBar-trial 14.1.0.37 and in order to crack it I have to put some .dll files in following location => C:Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL . but when I open assembly folder on my PC I just see no folders. here I upload a photo of the folder(it doesn't look like an ordinary folder).
please help me if you know what should I do to get to "GAC_MSIL" or to crak it.
Thanks a lot 
[assembly folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygEpr.jpg)
[ReadMe.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dIzN.jpg)

in all of the videos I have watched about it, they just enter C:Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL
and paste the .dll file in the told location.
but i have no idea what to do because "assembly" on my PC is just different from other PCs.
I guess there must be an option to be checked-in/out to change the view of the folder and return it to the default type as in other PCs.

Comment: Do you mean `[Drive]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`?

Comment: there is also a "GAC_MSIL" folder where you said but in the tutorials I've watched they said to put the crack file in C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL  not the "assembly" in "Microsoft.NET". are they the same? I mean is it ok to replace the file in the location you said?

Comment: Special folders / special files. You need to install your DLL(s). See [Gacutil.exe (Global Assembly Cache tool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool)

Comment: I kind of solved my problem by finding the registered version and installing it right now. but thank you anyway bro 